# Is IBM iSeries a 32 bit or 64 bit machine?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Just curious to know, if anyone knows whether iSeries (AS400) machine is a 32 bit or a 64 bit machine, like how windows is?

Comment: You might [find this question](http://superuser.com/questions/208312/how-to-tell-if-a-computer-has-a-64-bit-cpu-or-os) on SuperUser.com answers your question.

Comment: iSeries is a very old bit of hardware.  You are probably talking about a newer Power 5, 6, 7, or 8 machine.  You can use an internet search engine to find out about those hardware platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike some other virtual-machine architectures in which the virtual instructions are interpreted at run time, TIMI instructions are never interpreted. They constitute an intermediate compile time step and are translated into the processor's instruction set as the final compilation step. The TIMI instructions are stored within the final program object, in addition to the executable machine instructions. This is how application objects compiled on one processor family (e.g., the original CISC AS/400 48-bit processors) could be moved to a new processor (e.g., PowerPC 64-bit) without re-compilation. An application saved from the older 48-bit platform can simply be restored onto the new 64-bit platform where the operating system discards the old machine instructions and re-translates the TIMI instructions into 64-bit instructions for the new processor.
>
> The system's instruction set defines all pointers as 128-bit. This was the original design feature of the System/38 (S/38) in the mid 1970s planning for future use of faster processors, memory and an expanded address space. Today, 128-bit processors are already used for special purpose gaming and graphics applications. When at a point in the future 128-bit general purpose processors would appear, IBM i will already be fully 128-bit enabled. The original AS/400 CISC models used the same 48-bit address space as the S/38. The address space was expanded in 1995 when ith the RISC PowerPC RS64 64-bit CPU processor replaced the 48-bit CISC processor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_i